# Salary negotiations after verbal agreement

Tags: salary, negotiation

I had agreed verbally on an offer that was a more than my initial expectation. 
I am interested if I would be able to ask more of the base salary stating my lost compensations with my current employer.

During the discussion the hiring manager sounded positive about me being part of the team. On discussion further with the hiring manager I asked if the offer is set on stone. I also mentioned about the lost benefits at my current employer. The hiring manager encouraged me to negotiate(off record). I requested for a raise with the HR manager after the hiring manager was open.  But the HR manager mentioned she had forwarded my request to an approving manager and also mentioned nor the hiring manager would have no control of approval of requests. 
Question: Would this request cause me the offer?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you could give acceptable reasons that are acceptable to the company. Those reasons would consist of qualifications or benefits to the company you did not bring to the table when you were interviewing. There is little that would fit that description. Maybe if you completed a job specific training in the meantime that you did not mention before, or maybe you got divorced and now you *can* do all the overtime you said you'd rather not do. But any reasons why *you need more money* for the same deal are null and void. They are of no interest to the company.

If you verbally accepted all the details, then renegotiating them will come across as erratic, volatile and slightly illoyal. If however, the written contract contains details that you did not know when you accepted, then discussing them would be not as bad, especially if the are not standard and you did not expect them to be that way.

My experience is that although employers do all those checks and screens and interviews, as long as you haven't actually worked there, you are a potential risk. Once you did work there and proved them you are going to earn them money, it's a lot easier to ask them to give you more money in form of a raise. Once you got in, you have a way better position negotiating, if only for the fact that if you fail to get a raise you still got your job to fall back to as a base to either do better in the next round of raises or find another job.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did explain my situation to the hiring manager. He was open for negotiation

Comment: @nvoigt - My experience is exactly the opposite. Once you are working for a company, they know most people are reluctant to leave to go elsewhere. Thus, raises don't keep up with market rates. Which means people who have been at a company for a long time tend to be well below the market rate for their position. The best time and the best way to get a big raise and ahead of the market rate curve is to negotiate a big raise before accepting an offer from another company. You will never have more control over your salary than at that time. In fact, you have all of the control.